# Detect android java client connection timeout from PHP

Tags: java, php, android, http

I'm connecting from an android device using java to a server running PHP using DefaultHttpClient.

One test I am doing is to check that the java code gracefully handles itself if the server takes to long in sending data back. If it does take to long it disconnects and retries.

Currently I have setup the connection timeout to 3 seconds by:

```
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
```

On the server the PHP script is sleeping for 10 seconds:

```
sleep(10);
```

The java code works, if the script takes longer than 3 seconds then it throws a java.net.SocketTimeoutException and then retries again after a small amount of time.

The PHP script continues to run which is **not** what I want. I've tried testing using connection_aborted straight after the sleep function but it does not catch the client disconnect which has already happened.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
sleep(10);
print "black hole";
flush();
if(connection_aborted()!=0){
        // You would think this works but it does not.
}
```

Whats the recommended way to handle this?

Comment: What does the relevant php code look like?

Comment: @Phil the one simple line to sleep for 10 seconds.

Comment: @Phil I've added my attempt with connection_aborted

Answer (score 2):

I actually wrote an article on this very subject not too long ago, I will give a brief answer here, and assume it's ok to also post a related link?

Essentially, PHP will only figure out that a remote client has disconnected when it tries to use the socket that is connected to that remote socket, until you ask it to do anything with that socket it will assume that everything is fine. Here is the code I use to check for remote disconnections:

```
public function isAlive(){
        $res = @socket_recv($this->sockHandle, $data, 1024, MSG_PEEK);
        if($res === 0){
        return false;
        }else{
        return true;
        }
}
```

The important part here is the MSG_PEEK stops any pending messages from being cleared, and the "@" mutes errors if the socket is ok, but no messages are pending.

For the full article, it's available here:

http://www.bracketbrotherhood.com/remote-disconnections-php-non-blocking-server-sockets/programming-and-development/

Regards,
Phil,

Comment: Nice article to read and thanks for the answer. I've already pushed out the code so it may take me some time to get round testing your ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the same now, but a long time ago I ran into php not realizing the connection was aborted until it actually tried to write or flush its output buffers. See php's flush() and ob_flush(); I didn't need to actually write anything to output, just flushing empty buffers was enough to make it check.

I would imagine the webserver(s) and other stuff in front of php could affect this behavior.

You probably need to have already called ignore_user_abort(true); otherwise php will probably stop execution on the flush() call(default behavior is to stop when it realizes the connection is gone), so your if statement will never get executed.

Comment: Yes, it seems to point to the fact that the simple sleep script has not outputted anything. Let's see if a call to flush before the connection_abort function triggers it.

Answer (score -1):

```
print
"black hole";
flush();
if(connection_aborted()!=0){
      // You would think this works but it does not.
   }
```

Actually, you wouldn't think that that would work, because it would require the php script to get to that point in the script. If you wrote it at the end, then the script must run its course.

I would suggest instead:

```
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++){
    echo ' '; ## echo "\0";  might also work
    flush();
    if(connection_aborted()!=0){
          // You would think this works but maybe it will now.
          die();
       }
     sleep(1); # the sleep should come after the check
}
```

Give it a try. Clearly you are trying to sleep for 10 seconds and then kill the script... in all cases that script will run for 10 seconds.